# Definite Integral $x^{n} e^{x^2} $

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, error-function

I want to find an expression for the integral
\begin{align*}
\int x^{n} e^{x^2}~dx \quad or \int_{a}^{b} x^{n} e^{x^2}~dx.
\end{align*}
I tried this way:
\begin{align*}
\int x^{n} e^{x^2}~dx=\frac{1}{2}\int x^{n-1} 2x e^{x^2}~dx
\end{align*}
using integration by parts
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\int x^{n-1} (2x) e^{x^2}~dx=\frac{1}{2}x^{n-1}e^{x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\int(n-1) x^{n-2} e^{x^2}~dx
\end{align*}
This will continue ..... Is there any better way to deal with this integral?

Comment: The result will be in terms of the [incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html).

Comment: If we take the case with limits say $a$ to $b$, can we find an expression in terms of error function?

Comment: if $n$ is odd, I would start with the substitution $u = x^2$ and if $n$ is even you have something that can't be integrated into elementary functions.

Comment: Indeed, if $n$ is even, it reduces down to the error function.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand, even and odd $n$. Can you please explain me little more?

Comment: the problem is with the function $e^{x^2}$ it's what some would consider as hard to integrate, as we have yet to find an easy solution. this is where erf and erfi functions come into play. erf$(x):= \int e^{-x^2}dx$ and erfi$(x):= \int e^{x^2}dx$

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd, then $n=2k+1$, and by letting $u=x^2$, we get

$$\int x^ne^{x^2}\ dx=\frac12\int(x^2)^ke^{x^2}(2x\ dx)=\frac12\int u^ke^u\ du$$

Now consider the additional parameter:

$$\int e^{ut}\ du=\frac{e^{ut}}t$$

Differentiate $k$ times with respect to $t$ and you'll end up with

$$\int u^ke^u\ du=\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\frac{e^{x^2t}}t\bigg|_{t=1}$$

Thus,

$$\int x^ne^{x^2}\ dx=\frac12\frac{d^k}{dt^k}\frac{e^{ut}}t\bigg|_{t=1}+c$$

---

If $n$ is even, then $n=2k$,

$$\int x^ne^{x^2}\ dx=\int x^{2k}e^{x^2}\ dx$$

By integration by parts with $u=x^{2k-1}$ and $dv=xe^{x^2}\ dx$, we get

$$\int x^{2k}e^{x^2}\ dx=\frac12x^{2k-1}e^{x^2}-\frac{2k-1}2\int x^{2k-2}e^{x^2}\ dx$$

Which gives the reduction formula

$$I_k=\int x^{2k}e^{x^2}\ dx\\I_k=\frac12x^{2k-1}e^{x^2}-\frac{2k-1}2I_{k-1}$$

and with the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function),

$$I_0=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{erfi}(x)+c$$

$$I_{1/2}=\frac12e^{x^2}+c$$

(note that you can use $I_{1/2}$ to cover the odd case instead of using differentiation under the integral sign as I did above)